# Semicolon getting rendered in UI

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I have MVC code like below:

```
                <div class="testclass">
                    @{
                        IEnumerable<DisplayForm> assignment = val.Items.OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder ?? int.MaxValue);
                        int displayIndex = 0;
                    }
                    <div>
                        @foreach (DisplayFormItem displayItem in assignment)
                        {
                            if (displayIndex == 0)
                            {
                                if (displayItem.GetDisplayText(Model.ItemDisplayValue) == val.ItemDisplayName)
                                {
                                    @displayItem.Render(Model.Value, false, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @displayItem.Render(Model.Value, true, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="ls-propval-list">
                                    @displayItem.Render(Model.Value, true, Model.ItemDisplayValue);
                                </div>
                            }
                            displayIndex++;
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The issue I am facing is, when this above code is rendering in the UI, at the end, it is rendering ";" as well. If I comment "displayIndex++;" line, then it goes away. But I need that line and want the ";" to go away. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried it like that ? @{ displayIndex++;} ?

Comment: Yes, the page failed loading when I added '@{ displayIndex++;}'

Comment: Tried this '<span>@(displayIndex++)</span>'. But now it is rendering the count

Comment: @alexeiLevenkov that's true, when I removed the semicolon from previous line, it worked perfect :-) Thanks much